# Issue getting events Full Calendar asp.net / c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, fullcalendar

First of all i would say i have tried many many sample here and other not getting success so posting here for suggestion.

I am using Full Calendar.

Here is the start:

```
$('#calendar')
     .fullCalendar({
         allDaySlot: false,
         customButtons: {
             reload: {
                 text: '+1 Year',
                 click: function() {
                     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)));
                 }
             }                           
         },     
         themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
         defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
          eventClick: updateEvent,
          selectable: true,
          selectHelper: true,
         events: "JsonResponse.ashx", 
         and other attributes.....
```

The issue is the calendar is not showing events .

**JsonResonse.ashx**  returns a string like :

```
[{id: '1029',title: 'mr 1',clientphone: '1234556654',clientemail: 'mr1@gmail.com',start:  '2018-05-21 10:00',end: '2018-05-21 11:45',allDay:false,description: 'New test on a new calender'},{id: '1030',title: 'mr 2',clientphone: '123456',clientemail: 'mr2@gmail.com',start:  '2018-05-25 09:00',end: '2018-05-25 11:45',allDay:false,description: 'i like pringles'}]
```

However on firefox i see it does not make the events some error saying :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data
```

So i take the and Replace events: "JsonResponse.ashx", with the returned string

```
 [{id: '1029',title: 'mr 1',clientphone: '1234556654',clientemail: 'mr1@gmail.com',start:  '2018-05-21 10:00',end: '2018-05-21 11:45',allDay:false,description: 'New test on a new calender'},{id: '1030',title: 'mr 2',clientphone: '123456',clientemail: 'mr2@gmail.com',start:  '2018-05-25 09:00',end: '2018-05-25 11:45',allDay:false,description: 'i like pringles'}]
```

CODE TO MAKE THE JSON RETURN:

```
 return "{" +
             "id: '" + cevent.id + "'," +
             "title: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.title) + "'," +
             "clientphone: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.clientphone) + "'," +
             "clientemail: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.clientemail) + "'," +
             "start:  '" + (cevent.start).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") + "'," +
             "end: '" + (cevent.end).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") + "'," +
             "allDay:" + allDay + "," +
             "description: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.description) + "'" +
             "},";
```

Basically i combine all the events and then return.

just like that and it works fine and put events on the calendar . What am i doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: I have never used the library but a quick read of the docs, what you are doing is correct. The only thing I would try is on the server side, call `ToString` on the date property like this: `d.ToString("s")` so it is ISO 8601 because the docs say it has to be.

Comment: @CodingYoshi the same string does work if i just copy paste it ...

Comment: @CodingYoshi same error and startdate is now like ,start:  '2018-05-14T13:00:00'

But same json error showing

Comment: Ok another question, are you sure it is making a request and the ashx is returning data? And the data is valid JSON?

Comment: The data is returned YES and as above but i see in firefox it say Json Syntax error.. But same string i paste direclty in events and it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated question, you need to update the json generation code like this:

```
return "{" +
             "\"id\": \"" + cevent.id + "\"," +
             "\"title\": \"" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.title) + "\"," +
             "\"clientphone\": \"" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.clientphone) + "\"," +
             "\"clientemail\": \"" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.clientemail) + "\"," +
             "\"start\":  \"" + (cevent.start).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") + "\"," +
             "\"end\": \"" + (cevent.end).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") + "\"," +
             "\"allDay\":" + allDay + "," +
             "\"description\": \"" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.description) + "\"" +
             "},";
```

Comment: Now its like : 
[{"id": "1029" , "title": "ehsan kayani" , "clientphone": "03405186307" , "clientemail": "ehsan@gmail.com" ,  "start": "2018-05-21 10:00" ,  "end": "2018-05-21 11:45" ,  "allday": "false" , "description": "New test on a new calender"},{"id": "1030" , "title": "ehsan kayani" , "clientphone": "123456" , "clientemail": "hafs@gmail.com" ,  "start": "2018-05-25 09:00" ,  "end": "2018-05-25 11:45" ,  "allday": "false" , "description": "hafsa is very good kid"}]
no more errors but it still did not populate on caledar

Comment: Thank you it does work without the ISO format too. I was looking at the wrong dates :)  the "" fix worked .

Answer (score 0):

The json returned by JsonResponse.ashx handler is invalid. How are you generating the json? I suggest use [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serializing your Events list as json using [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) method

Here is the valid json that your ashx handler should return. Note the double quotes around property name and values.

```
[{
    "id": "1029",
    "title": "mr1",
    "clientphone": "1234556654",
    "clientemail": "mr1@gmail.com",
    "start": "2018-05-2110: 00",
    "end": "2018-05-2111: 45",
    "allDay": false,
    "description": "Newtestonanewcalender"
},
{
    "id": "1030",
    "title": "mr2",
    "clientphone": "123456",
    "clientemail": "mr2@gmail.com",
    "start": "2018-05-2509: 00",
    "end": "2018-05-2511: 45",
    "allDay": false,
    "description": "ilikepringles"
}]
```

Comment: I added another answer for fixing the generated json